# from date and to date not between in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have two dates 30-01-2017 & 02-02-2017

Need a condition in cakephp to search record these two dates doesn't lies in between.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.I think this would be helpful.

```
$searchFirstdate = '30-01-2017';
$searchLastdate  = '02-02-2017';

$this->ModelName->find(
    'all',array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'ModelName .date_field >= ' => $searchFirstdate,
            'ModelName .date_field <= ' => $searchLastdate
         )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `NOT BETWEEN` operand for MYSQL, so you could easily use:

```
$this->ModelName->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'ModelName.date_field NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array('30-01-2017', '02-02-2017')
    )
));
```

From CakePHP [Manual](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions)